# Is there a Script that gives me a Filtered Table based on the words that were “checked” on checkbox - Google Sheet

Tags: javascript, macos, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a data set and I am trying to build a “searcher” where the user checks the checkboxes of the different criteria’s and after it has chosen all the criteria’s (can be more than 1), it shows a Filtered Table that only has the rows from the data set of which the criteria(s) that were checked appeared.

I tried using FilterCriteria or Query, but don’t seem to make it work efficiently. Since there are more 30 criteria to choose from and it can mix and match between them. For example, on the first stage (Level 1) there 2 criterias to choose from (which should filter the column H from the picture below), then there a set of criterias, around 20 (Level 2 and 3), that the user can choose multiple options (columns I - N).

For example, if the user picks Option 1 in Level 1, Option A4 in Level 2 and Option B4 in Level 3, the table should be just the row 9 (# 005, which has Result #5).

[Explanation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNxsP.jpg)

Comment: HI and welcome. "I tried using FilterCriteria or Query, but don’t seem to make it work efficiently. " I'm not entirely surprised given that there are so many potential variables. Would you explain, must a user make a selection for Level 1 AND Level 2 AND Level 3, or could they just select Level 3 alone? That is, does it have to be hierarchical? Anyway, would you please share the query/filter formula(s) that you write.

Comment: "For example, if the user picks Option 1 in Level 1, Option A4 in Level 2 and Option B4 in Level 3, the table should be just the row 9 (# 005, which has Result #5)." Would you please explain why Result#1 does not also meet the selection criteria - it contains "Option1" AND "Option A4" AND "Option B4".

Comment: Hi Tedinoz - The User can returned table should be based on the Criteria choosen. For instance it should work with just Level 1 and Level 2, but ideal is to have all 3 Levels to make the most accurate result. Regarding the second comment, you are right, Result #001 could also work, I didn´t notice when I did the example.

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula:

`=query({query({query({G5:O9},"select * where Col2 Matches "&"'"&join("|",query({$B$5:$C$5;$D$5:$E$5},"select Col2 where Col1 = true"))&"'")},"select * where Col3 Matches "&"'"&join("|",query({$B$7:$C$13;$D$7:$E$12},"select Col2 where Col1 = true"))&"' or Col4 Matches "&"'"&join("|",query({$B$7:$C$13;$D$7:$E$12},"select Col2 where Col1 = true"))&"' or Col5 Matches "&"'"&join("|",query({$B$7:$C$13;$D$7:$E$12},"select Col2 where Col1 = true"))&"'")},"select * where Col6 Matches "&"'"&join("|",query({$B$15:$C$18;$D$15:$E$18},"select Col2 where Col1 = true"))&"' or Col7 Matches "&"'"&join("|",query({$B$15:$C$18;$D$15:$E$18},"select Col2 where Col1 = true"))&"' or Col8 Matches "&"'"&join("|",query({$B$15:$C$18;$D$15:$E$18},"select Col2 where Col1 = true"))&"'")`

The logic is based on a progression of selecting records that match:

- Level 1 (Col2), then

  - Level 2 (Col3, Col4 & Col5), then

    - Level 3 (Col6, Col7 & Col8)
- each `where` statement uses:

  - `matches`, and
  - `join`
- the `join` formula uses a query as the input for "value or array"

  - the query is based on the respective option level groups
  - because each option group covers 2 sets of columns (B&C, and D&E), the query range stacks the data for the columns. For example:

    - Level 1: `query({$B$5:$C$5;$D$5:$E$5},"select Col2 where Col1 = true")`

Comment: This formula assumes that the user shall select options from Level 1 AND Level 2 AND Level 3.  That's why there is no error-checking in this formula. However, if I understand your most recent comment correctly, you've said that a user should select options from both Level 1 and Level 2; Level 3 options are optional. Those "selection rules" would require an error-checking modification to the formula.